# Unable to edit ORG1MSPanchors.tx in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm trying to edit the file ORG1MSPanchors.tx, so I've executed the following commands:

```
-> configtxlator proto_decode --input ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.tx --type common.Envelope >channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.json
-> nano channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.json
-> configtxlator proto_encode --input ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.json --type common.Envelope >./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.tx
```

But the changes are not made in ORG1MSPanchors.tx. Does anyone know why this might be? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Use output flag instead of ">"

```
configtxlator proto_decode --input ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.tx --type common.Envelope --output ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.json
configtxlator proto_encode --input ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.json --type common.Envelope --output ./channel-artifacts/ORG1MSPanchors.tx
```

Comment: Hello @Christopher, thank you for your reply. I still have the same problem, I generate the json file from the tx file, edit it, and generate the tx file again from the modified json file. When I re-generate the json file from the modified tx file, the changes are not saved.

Comment: Try save it with a different name